# Problem with webclient: Expectation failed?

Tags: visual-studio, httphandler, webclient, system.net.webexception

I have a custom Http Handler which manipulates HTTP POST and GET. I got the project working on a seperate isolated server now need to put it in production...

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                    client.UploadFile("serverlocation:port", fileToUpload);
                }
```

---

For some reason now when using `client.UploadFile("", file);` i.e. forcing the HTTP POST

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (417) Expectation failed.

   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadFile(Uri address, String method, String fileName)
```

What could this be? I know the code works, so what else? Maybe the server blocks HTTP POST requests?

I have tried adding:

`ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;`

But have had no success though i'm not 100% sure where this code should before, I assume before i'm using the WebClient

---

**Edit 0 :**

I have just [read](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/d5d85e6d-b870-4057-82c8-49bf849c98f5) the following:

*Because of the presence of older implementations, the protocol allows
   ambiguous situations in which a client may send "Expect: 100-
   continue" without receiving either a 417 (Expectation Failed) status
   or a 100 (Continue) status. Therefore, when a client sends this
   header field to an origin server (possibly via a proxy) from which it
   has never seen a 100 (Continue) status, the client SHOULD NOT wait
   for an indefinite period before sending the request body.*

I believe this request is going through a proxy, which may have something to do with the issue.

**Edit 1:**

Believe this problem has to be with 100-continue because, using fiddler to see exactly what my application is sending with `WebClient.UploadFile` shows this:

```
POST http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8091/file.myhandledextension HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------8ccd1eb03f78bc2
Host: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8091
Content-Length: 4492
Expect: 100-continue
```

Despite having put that line: `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;` before the using statement. I don't think this line actually works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up solving this by putting the `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;` in the constructor for the calling WebClient class.

Then I used [Fiddler](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCAQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fiddler2.com%2Ffiddler2%2Fversion.asp&ei=Z14ITMO8J8mDcOub2IEO&usg=AFQjCNE9h32pBsq5Nv000r2subMLAXwJ4A) to examine the POST request to ensure `Expect: 100-continue` was not in the request anymore.